# MongoDB: Remove time portion from a DateTime String

Tags: mongodb

I have a date/time string and I would like to convert it to a date without the time. I would like to add another field to store this new value. I tried the below but it doesn't work. Is there a way to remove the time portion from the string ?

Object

```
[{ 
 
    "ID" : "001247174102", 
    "VersionInfo" : {
        "IsLatestVersion" : true, 
        "VersionDate" : "2019-09-19T10:23:46.429-06:00"
    }
}]


TESTONE = {
   $addFields: {
      DateTest: {$dateFromString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", dateString: "$VersionInfo.VersionDate",    onNull: new Date(0)} }
   }
};
```

Comment: Storing date/time values as string is a design flaw, use always proper `Date` objects. In Mongo 5.0 you can use [$dateTrunc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateTrunc/#mongodb-expression-exp.-dateTrunc) to remove the time part, i.e. set time to `00:00:00`

Comment: I know but I can't change the database anymore :(

Answer (score 1):

As already written you you should **never** store date/time values as string. So in this case, first make proper `Date` objects and then set time to `00:00:00`:

```
{
   $addFields: {
      DateTest: {
         $dateFromString: { 
           format: "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%Lz", 
           dateString: "$VersionInfo.VersionDate",    
           onNull: new Date(0)
         } 
      }
   }
},
{
   $set: {
      DayTest: {
         $dateFromParts: { 
           year: {$year: "$DateTest"}, 
           month: {$month: "$DateTest"}, 
           day: {$dayOfMonth: "$DateTest"}
         }
      }
   }
},
```

If you run already Mongo version 5.0 you can make it shorter:

```
{
   $addFields: {
      DateTest: {
         $dateFromString: { 
           format: "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%Lz", 
           dateString: "$VersionInfo.VersionDate",    
           onNull: new Date(0)
         } 
      }
   }
},
{
   $set: {
      DayTest: {
         $dateTrunc: { 
           date: "$DateTest",
           unit: "day"
         }
      }
   }
},
```